# How do I generate a uniqueidentifier for a set of records with a distinct key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, common-table-expression

I have a record set that looks like this:

```
| key_sk | unique_id                            |
|--------|--------------------------------------|
| 2      | null                                 |
| 2      | null                                 |
| 3      | 83a1c90b-e58d-4db4-b438-a79edfb28e60 |
| 3      | 83a1c90b-e58d-4db4-b438-a79edfb28e60 |
| 4      | 4ce66783-0b84-4e8a-a0de-c3284e4d9cd0 |
| 5      | null                                 |
```

I would like to generate a unique id for each unique `key_sk` set where the `unique_id` is null. For the above I'd like `key_sk 2` to have a a single `unique_id` like `key_sk 3` does.

My attempt below generated a different `uniqueidentifier` for each set. I think this is because of the recursive nature of common table expressions: each join to the CTE causes `NEWID()` to be called.

```sql
;with update_id_cte as
(
  select distinct hr.key_sk
        ,NEWID() as gened_unique_id
    from history_record hr
   where hr.unique_id is null
)
update hr
   set hr.unique_id = cte.gened_unique_id
  from history_record hr
       join update_id_cte cte
         on hr.key_sk = cte.key_sk
```

There's probably a simpler way than utilizing a CTE to do this. How can I generate and update the `history_record` table with a single `uniqueidentifier` for each distinct `key_sk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In at least older version of MySQL this can be a pain as you are checking and want to check the same column, one way to do it is with temporary tables.

This is not one query but rather part of a stored procedure, but if you only going to do it once it's you can just run it.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp
select distinct hr.key_sk ,NEWID() as gened_unique_id
from history_record hr
where hr.unique_id is null;

update hr
set hr.unique_id = tmp.gened_unique_id
from history_record hr
inner join tmp on hr.key_sk = tmp.key_sk;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that it should work as you expect if you first select distinct `key_sk` in a subquery, then assign a new id. This way, the `newid()` is invoked only once per distinct target `key_sk`:

```
with update_id_cte as (
    select key_sk, newid() as gened_unique_id
    from (select distinct key_sk from history_record where unique_id is null) t
)
update hr
set hr.unique_id = cte.gened_unique_id
from history_record hr
inner join update_id_cte cte on hr.key_sk = cte.key_sk
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `select distinct`, you can use `group by`:

```
with update_id_cte as (
       select hr.key_sk, NEWID() as gened_unique_id
       from history_record hr
       where hr.unique_id is null
       group by hr.key_sk
      )
update hr
   set hr.unique_id = cte.gened_unique_id
   from history_record hr join
        update_id_cte cte
        on hr.key_sk = cte.key_sk;
```

If it is possible that some `key_sk` values have both `NULL` and not-`NULL` keys AND you want to preserve existing values, you can tweak the logic:

```
with update_id_cte as (
       select hr.key_sk, coalesce(max(hr.unique_id), NEWID()) as gened_unique_id
       from history_record hr
       group by hr.key_sk
      )
update hr
   set hr.unique_id = cte.gened_unique_id
   from history_record hr join
        update_id_cte cte
        on hr.key_sk = cte.key_sk
   where hr.unique_id is null;
```

Comment: Thankfully, I don't have a mixed set, but out of curiosity how does the max(hr.unique_id, NEWID()) work? Would an isnull` be the same? Also why does the `group by` make a difference in this case vs. the `distinct`?

Comment: @ahsteele . . . That was a typo.

Comment: Does this work? I expected it would and tried a similar solution for this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70608210/update-column-with-the-same-value-for-all-rows-that-have-the-same-value-in-anoth/70608306#70608306 However my testing, shows a unique id for each row?

Comment: I suspect this is the reason it may not work. https://sqlsunday.com/2013/10/06/exec-order-of-nondeterm-funcs/