# Update column with the same value for all rows that have the same value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given the following example table schema and data:

```
create table Example(
   Id int not null,
   Col1 int not null,
   Col2 uniqueidentifier null,
);
```

```
insert into Example 
values 
(1, 1, NULL), (2, 1, NULL), (3, 1, NULL), (4, 2, NULL), (5, 3, NULL), (6, 3, NULL)
```

Which generates:

| Id | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | NULL |
| 3 | 1 | NULL |
| 4 | 2 | NULL |
| 5 | 3 | NULL |
| 6 | 3 | NULL |

I would like help, if possible, in writing a script which would update Col2 for all rows with the same `newid()` based on the same value of Col1.

Ex of que table after the script is executed:

| Id | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | bad34c74-f546-4d79-804b-d048d8c7d977 |
| 2 | 1 | bad34c74-f546-4d79-804b-d048d8c7d977 |
| 3 | 1 | bad34c74-f546-4d79-804b-d048d8c7d977 |
| 4 | 2 | e464b79a-b97c-4192-a4f3-327cc147cc4a |
| 5 | 3 | 99475e8f-2788-4c63-817f-4deb130440ab |
| 6 | 3 | 99475e8f-2788-4c63-817f-4deb130440ab |

Much appreciated for any help

Comment: Unless this is a temporary step on route to dropping Col1 this indicates a normalisation problem as Col2 is functionally dependent on Col1. You should have another table with the distinct `Col1` and their associated `Col2`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes. I understand. But for this specific example I'm only interested in the problem/solution itself, please disregard the normalisation problem.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to do it in two steps.

```
UPDATE Example
SET Col2 = NEWID()

UPDATE e1
SET Col2 = e2.Col2
FROM Example e1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
             FROM Example
             WHERE Col1 = e1.Col1
             ORDER BY Col2) e2
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with a common table expression. The `UNION` is [required](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1748496) so that the subquery is materialized.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT Col1, NEWID() AS UniqueID
    FROM Example
    GROUP BY Col1
    UNION
    SELECT NULL, NEWID()
)
UPDATE e
SET Col2 = cte.UniqueID
FROM Example e
INNER JOIN cte ON cte.Col1 = e.Col1
```